# what is the point of go client.receive() in this code?

Tags: go, concurrency

```
func (client *Client) receive() {
    var err error
    for err == nil {
        var h codec.Header
        if err = client.cc.ReadHeader(&h); err != nil {
            break
        }
        call := client.removeCall(h.Seq)
        switch {
        case call == nil:
            // it usually means that Write partially failed
            // and call was already removed.
            err = client.cc.ReadBody(nil)
        case h.Error != "":
            call.Error = fmt.Errorf(h.Error)
            err = client.cc.ReadBody(nil)
            call.done()
        default:
            err = client.cc.ReadBody(call.Reply)
            if err != nil {
                call.Error = errors.New("reading body " + err.Error())
            }
            call.done()
        }
    }
    // error occurs, so terminateCalls pending calls
    client.terminateCalls(err)
}

func NewClient(conn net.Conn, opt *Option) (*Client, error) {
    f := codec.NewCodecFuncMap[opt.CodecType]
    if f == nil {
        err := fmt.Errorf("invalid codec type %s", opt.CodecType)
        log.Println("rpc client: codec error:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    // send options with server
    if err := json.NewEncoder(conn).Encode(opt); err != nil {
        log.Println("rpc client: options error: ", err)
        _ = conn.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    return newClientCodec(f(conn), opt), nil
}

func newClientCodec(cc codec.Codec, opt *Option) *Client {
    client := &Client{
        seq:     1, // seq starts with 1, 0 means invalid call
        cc:      cc,
        opt:     opt,
        pending: make(map[uint64]*Call),
    }
    go client.receive()
    return client
}
```

I am new to Go, here is a snippet of code of rpc.
what is the point of `go client.receive()`? `return client` will execute instantly and will not wait for `client.receive()` to execute, so `newClientCodec()` will return, client.receive() does nothing?  I don't know if I am right? Please point out where I am wrong and give explanations.

Comment: `client.receive()` runs a processing loop - it will return  on error - but it loops continuously otherwise. And it is run in its own goroutine. The `newClientCodec` returns a reference to the client - so callers can  interact with this. Looks like a standard client setup to me.

Comment: @colm.anseo  Thanks for your comment. Do you mean the coroutine `client. receive()` will run independently regardless of the main routine call it terminates not?

Comment: ```func main() {
 go test()
 return
}

func test() {
 for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
 log.Println(i)
 }
}```I am confused that a program like this will not print the value in its goroutine as the main thread terminates before the goroutine executes, which is contradicted to the assumption above.

Comment: Only if the main function ends, the program existed and all goroutines terminate. If you want to check this, put a select{} statement at the end of main function.